# Как сделать график на C#

Tags: c#, график

Как сделать график подобный этому:
[image]

Answer (score 8):

Рекомендую [ZedGraph](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/).

> ZedGraph is a class library, user control, and web control for .net, written in C#, for drawing 2D Line, Bar, and Pie Charts. It features full, detailed customization capabilities, but most options have defaults for ease of use

Comment: Удобная и действительно простая в использовании, судя по примерам.
Но немного не то, не такая уж она и красивая, с визуальной точки зрения.

Comment: Аа. Ну вообще когда я пользовался этой библиотечкой, она имела весьма богатые возможности по настройке внешнего вида графиков. Так что может стоит поиграться подольше.

Comment: А в WPF Toolkit можно сделать что нибудь достойное ?
Но это уже придется работать в WPF который я не очень то люблю

Comment: Про WPF Toolkit не в курсе.

Answer (score 3):

Посмотрите в сторону [библиотеки контролов для рисования графиков](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nplot/)

Comment: Не осилил.

Answer (score 3):

Здравствуйте, я уже отвечал вам на этот вопрос [здесь](http://www.gotdotnet.ru/forums/17/144626/680847/#post680847), но видимо вы его так и не прочли.
Ну что ж напишу еще раз:
[первый](http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/) и
[второй](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart)

Answer (score 0):

А как насчет стандартного [Chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.aspx) ?